# Is there a way to extract a value from a string which is separated by a certain character?

Tags: java, android, string

My app reads a value of a NFC tag which contains plain text, to then cut the read String up.
The string should be as follow:
"r=v;b=v;g=v;n=v;p=v;m=v;s=v"
I want to read the "v" characters, since they are divided by the ; character, and i remember there being a function that let me divide strings like this, how do i do it? The v value isn't constant, it could span 1 position like it could span 3 or 4. The app is for Android phones, written in Java on Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about String method [.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

it's splits string into array and so for you question, since split can work with regex you can split exactly for needed patterns
like this:

```
String givenString="r=v;b=v;g=v;n=v;p=v;m=v;s=v";
        String[]vs=givenString.split("([;]?[a-z]{1}[=])");
        for(String v: vs){System.out.println(v);}//prints all v
```

Regex explanation:

1. [;]? -> means may start with one semicolon or none
2. [a-z]{1} -> means one letter lower case only
3. [=] -> means equals sign

**Edit:** if you use split by only semicolon (as @cvester suggested), you get the whole entry string, such as: "r=v","b=v", etc..
in this case you can iterate over all entries and then make one more split by equals "=" like this:

```
String []entries=givenString.split(";");
        for (String entry:entries){
            String []vs=entry.split("=");
            System.out.println(vs[1]);//prints all v
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java has a split function on a String.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

So you can just use split(";");

Comment: Oh thank you, i knew the answer was obvious, i just couldn't remember the function at all, even looking throught all the functions listed... thanks again!

Comment: @cvesters if he splits only by semicolon as you suggested, he gets the whole entry string "k=v", but he asked for only "v".
This way he will need another split by "=" sign for each entry. something like that:
String []entries=givenString.split(";");
    for (String entry:entries){
     String []vs=entry.split("=");
     System.out.println(vs[1]);
    }

Comment: I assumed he needed both, because what's the point of having just the 'v'? I believe it is the key - value combination that is interesting. And the first step for this is to split on';'. After that you can extract the key and value by splitting again on '='

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#split()` or you could create your own logic.

```
String string = "r=v;b=asfasv;g=v;n=asf;p=v;m=v;s=vassaf";
    String word = "";
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
    while(i < string.length())
    {
      if(string.charAt(i) == '=')
       {
           i++;
         while( i < string.length() && string.charAt(i) != ';' )
            {
              word += string.charAt(i);
              i++;
            }
         list.add(word);
         System.out.println(word);
         word = "";
       } 
      i ++;
    }
    if(!word.equals(""))
     list.add(word);

    System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to avoid looping

```
String input = "r=v;b=v;g=v;n=v;p=v;m=v;s=v";
input.trim().replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]=)+","").replaceAll(";",""));
```